# 3d reverse masking of volumetric

Tags: volumetrics, masking, compositing-nodes

Is it possible to create a volumetric cube but mask only the space of that volumetric cube by a mesh?

Hence if I put Suzanne inside the volumetric I only see her?
The effect I am looking for is how at night with a torch if you shine it in smoke you only see the smoke as it passes through the light ray. I want to make shock wave torus rings that mask a volumetric cube with a random noise, so that the torus rings only expose the smoke.

Comment: I hope you do not mind my edit. I think it will be easier to read this for people who might be willing to help. The title says "3d reverse masking of volumetric" Could you clarify?  What do you mean by "reverse"?

Comment: How about using a spot light?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understood the reason, why don't use Torus directly with Volumetric material? Can you post some reference?

Answer (score 1):

### Volumetric Cube catching Torus Light

Is this what you are looking for?

- *Cube* with *Principled Volume* Shader
  (*Density* 0.1 / *Anisotropy* 0.95)
- *Torus* with *Emission* Shader
  (*Properties editor > Object > Visibility > Ray Visibility > Camera* OFF)

So what you see is only light rays catching on Volumetric

[image]

[image]

Something more colourful ... Torus with Noise texture and Displacement Modifier.

[image]
[image]